# Conbee II on /dev/ttyACM0 on Raspi not found

Tags: usb, ssd, raspberry-pi

I've got a new Raspberry Pi 4B running on a SSD, fresh install.
Now I try to setup my Conbee2 stick, it connects, is visible with `lsusb` and with removing+adding it shows with `dmesg`, but trying to update/flash the stick manually gives an error **device /dev/ttyACM0 not found**. Also in the Phoscon web App no changes can be made, no lights are found etc.

Everything worked fine on my old RasPi4 with SD-card. In this setup the only thing that changed is the SSD in stead of the SD-card... could it be an power issue? I've got an official RasPi adapter connected. How can I discover if this is the problem? Any tips or tricks on this?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:1153 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1cf1:0030 Dresden Elektronik ZigBee gateway [ConBee II]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Measure the voltage to see if its dropping